# How to write mysql query for changing variable

Tags: mysql, variables, loops

The following are three tables that I need to do a query on.

```
r601_shoppingcart_carts
  cart_id          user_id          customize 
   10               65                 1
   11               78                 1
   12               78                 0

r601_shoppingcart_items:
cart_item_id   cart_id     sobipro_entry     
    5              10            87
   39              11           194
   40              11           140 
   38              12           126

r601_sobipro_field_data
fid                sid          baseData
 45                194          cg_0059
 45                140          cg_0094_4
 45                141          cg_0011_2
```

The desired result of the query will provide the baseData (Product No) for a particular user (user_id) cart if that item (Product) was customizable

In this instance the correct retrieved data should show that user_id 78 has the following two customizable items in his/her cart:
cg_0059
cg_0094_4

Earlier, I displayed here a SELECT statement that was way out in left-field. I found that the following SELECT statement achieved what I was aiming for. I do not know whether it is an efficient statement or not. Any comments would be appreciated.

```
 SELECT
    r601_sobipro_field_data.baseData,
    r601_sobipro_field_data.sid,
    r601_shoppingcart_items.cart_id,
    r601_shoppingcart_carts.cart_id
 FROM
    r601_sobipro_field_data,
    r601_shoppingcart_items,
    r601_shoppingcart_carts
 WHERE
    r601_sobipro_field_data.fid = 45
 AND
    r601_sobipro_field_data.sid = r601_shoppingcart_items.sobipro_entry 
 AND
    r601_shoppingcart_items.cart_id = r601_shoppingcart_carts.cart_id
 AND
    r601_shoppingcart_carts.user_id = 78
 AND
    r601_shoppingcart_carts.customize = 1
```

I did receive one helpful message. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the line:

```
$partNo = $sobiBaseData_rows[$i]->baseData;
```

Since the value returned by the query returns a separate array, you cannot access the $i element.

if there is only one value returned everytime, you can access it as:

```
$partNo = $sobiBaseData_rows[0]->baseData;
```

If multiple values are returned, you can loop over the values and store it in an array.